# How to implement Breadcrumb Navigation in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I want to implement breadcrumb navigation in my iOS application. How could this possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The HIG tells you not to do this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1

Answer (score 2):

If you use a navigation controller, you can easily access its stack of view controllers using the `viewControllers` property. There's no built-in "breadcrumb" control, so you'll have to do the drawing yourself, possibly with a sequence of buttons. When a user taps one of the buttons, you can use UINavigationController's `popToViewController:animated:` method to go straight to that view controller.

As screen space is constrained on small iOS devices, you might want to consider doing the "normal" thing and just using a stock navigation controller. It's unusual in iOS to have to drill down through a great many screens, so a few taps on the "Back" button in the navigation bar will usually get users where they want to go.